# Missing=inserted for \ifnum

Tags: beamer, errors, missing

I have error « `! Missing=inserted for \ifnum. <to be read again> - \usedictionary`

My code is

```
\documentclass[10pt,pdf,hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russianb]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\else
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\fi
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}\frametitle{Название кадра}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
            Содержимое левого столбца
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
            Содержимое правого столбца
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

What to do? Thank You!

Comment: Works okay for me. Show your log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer something with translator. I have installed it. And there are a lot of questions about it in stack exchange. But what to do with translator?

Comment: Just a note, most of the times `graphicx` is smart enough to detect the correct driver on its own, and you don't have to specify `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` but just do `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Comment: @Skillmon They are in the comment. And it doesn’t depend on my problem

Comment: @DozzyCooper and that's why I started my comment with "Just a note". Even though it's not the problem at hand, it is important to tell people about best practices. How else should they learn?

Comment: Please add your .log file